# Wemos D1 doesnt drive Relay

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266, power, relay

I recently bought a Wemos D1 board and tried to connect a relay and test its connection.

I got an [example server](http://www.esp8266learning.com/wemos-webserver-example.php) from here and executed. I connected D5 to a Relay's data and 5v and GND from Wemos board.

But this does not change the state of relay, it always remains high. I connected a LED for D5, it works perfectly with client's response.

Then I powered relay using an external 5v and ground connection, but the same result.

I have checked for possible solution, but coulnt find an answer.

The relay I am using is [this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00O9WPAJ6)

Comment: Normally it is because people work under the misconception that D5 in the code is D5 on the board, but using the LED means you are using the right port in the code and hardware, so have you looked at it the board can supply enough current to trigger the relay (it only outputs <20mA).

Comment: Sounds like the pin cannot provide enough current to drive the relais. Try to use a transistor or MOSFET for it

Comment: @chrisl can you provide me an example? I am not good with electronic stuffs. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: You may need a BJT transistor to amplify the current. Look at https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/220492/safely-pull-5v-to-gnd-on-3-3v-gpio. Do you use a bare-bones relay or a relay board? Which one exactly?

Comment: you have a relay module? add a link to it

Comment: @chrisl if the relay has separate power and signal pins, I would think that it is a relay module with supporting circuit

Comment: Please give a link to the exact relay you are using.

Comment: Many of the cheap 5v relay modules i've gotten don't work because the D1 runs on 3.3v, so it's high is not enough to trigger the relay. fwiw, every dual-relay module i've gotten works on 3.3v boards, but there's not reason on paper why that should be the case, it just happens to be true; maybe they use better driving electronics in the dual modules...

Comment: the relay you linked has no digital pin. how did you wire it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The board which you are using is operating on 3v3. Even if you try to run the relay using the D5 or any other pin on the board, you may not be able to run it successfully at all times. In this case, you can go for either MOSFETs or Pull-up resistors so that you can hold the voltage to 5V for triggering the relay. I would personally suggest to go for a PNP type.

As requested by Sachith, here is the circuit suggested for the problem stated. Just note that the voltage source should be `+5 V` (which is `+1 V` in the schematic). Also, the MOSFET is not the specific one, it is just for the schematic purpose.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZ1U1v.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I would expect that a 5 V TTL senses 3.3 V as HIGH. I think he has some other problem.

Comment: @Juraj: your expectations are too high for fleabay modules; i have several single-relay boards that work perfect at 5v, but spotty or not at all on 3.3v...

Comment: @dandavis, with 5 V power supply  and 3.3 V signal?

Comment: @Juraj: yes, with 5v in from usb, 3.3v i/o on ESP, many are sporadic at best

Comment: but patching the module's on-board TTL circuit with external MOSFET?  is it a good answer? if I would want to care about electronics details, the I would take a plain relay

Comment: @Juraj I understand that it feels awkward to have a TTL with external MOSFET, but the best solution could be possible only when we would be clear with the actual scenario. So, Sachith please let us know which relay you are actually trying in your case. If possible, share a link of the same.

Comment: @SumitPanse I have updated the relay I am using.

Comment: Okay @Sachith. I saw that update just now. I would need a little time to check and revert back on it.

Comment: @Sachith, how did you wire it?

Comment: @Juraj https://www.amazon.ca/Indicator-Light-Channel-Module-Arduino/dp/B00P7QDJD2

Comment: @SumitPanse Can you give an example of the circuit I need to implement? I do not have a good electronic knowledge.

Comment: so, this is a module. it needs 5 V VCC and not specified signal level, where 3.3 V doesn't work. buy one which accepts 3.3 V as HIGH

Comment: @Sachith I have updated and modified my answer with the circuit you have requested. Please check it let me know whether it is clear to you or not.

Comment: @SumitPanse thanks for the updated answer.  So I should use `P1` = `D5` and 5v supply to `J310` MOSFET.

Comment: @Sachith I have taken `J310` just for reference. But yes, other connections can be done as per the schematic.